# Start/access emulator from ssh or with built images

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-source

For a school project i have to modify AOSP to create our own custom android (7.1.2 version).
We setup a server (ubuntu server 17) who can build it, and it works.

The problem is when we want the emulator to test the builted android.
We can't start it from the server, cause it doesn't have a display.

We tried to start it with my computer (with ubuntu 18 os), to do this i downloaded Android Studio and setup an AVD with Android 7.1.1, and when i start the emulator i specify -system and -ramdisk, as i see here: [custom android emulator](https://sites.google.com/site/androidkernelwiki/howtos/HowToRunCustomEmulator)

It starts sometime (sometime i have just blackscreens) but i didn't see my edits in the settings app (i add a "rom name" value)

I read something about "emulator networking" but it didn't seems to solve my problem, i want to see the android built running in a window.

Can anyone help me ?
Thank you in advance.